# How can I Save Report.Document.Printer settings?

Tags: c#, activereports

I want store the Report.Document.Printer settings in a database,
how can I Save it?
Is there any way like the Report.SaveLayout() method?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in save method like SaveLayout, but you could save these settings yourself into text or XML (for example) to save in your database and manually reset them later.

You can see an example of setting those properties in [the Printer class documentation page](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/ActiveReports6_start.html?ActiveReports.Document~DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Document.Printer.html). For your needs, you would just retrieve those settings from your database (the text/xml) instead of hard coding them as is done in the example.

Answer (score 0):

try PrintDocument.PrinterSettings